# Change spring cloud loadbalancer default RoundRobin Algorithm

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I'm trying to migrate from Ribbon to Spring Cloud LoadBalancer because Ribbon is now in maintenance mode, and I can't add ribbon dependency in spring initialize using the default spring-boot 2.4.2 version. I'm currently using OpenFeign and I'm doing some test trying to change the default RoundRobin Load Balancer configuration to Random Rule. This is what I have

When using Ribbon I just had to change the default configuration

```
@Configuration
public class RibbonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public IRule loadBalancingRule() {
//        return new RoundRobinRule();
        return new RandomRule();
    }

}
```

And add the annotation @RibbonClient in the client (also works adding it in the MainApplication class)

```
@FeignClient("first-service")
@RibbonClient(name = "first-service", configuration = RibbonConfiguration.class)
public interface HelloClient {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    String hello();
}
```

But I can't make it works using spring-cloud-loadbalancer. I know is included by default in the spring-cloud-starter-openfeign dependency so my pom is like this

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>edge-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>edge-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Having my FeignClients like this (without any Ribbon annotation)

```
@FeignClient("first-service")
public interface HelloClient {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    String hello();
}

@FeignClient("second-service")
public interface WorldClient {
    @GetMapping("/world")
    String world();
}
```

And my RestController like this

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @Autowired
    private HelloClient helloClient;
    @Autowired
    private WorldClient worldClient;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    
    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public String helloWorld() {
        logger.info("Calling the clients");
        return helloClient.hello() + " - " + worldClient.world();
    }
}
```

Without doing anything else it seems to works the load balancing (with two instance of hello-service running still working and is calling alternate), but I want to change the default loadbalancer algorithm (RoundRobin) to anotherone (like random or anyone custom) to test the difference. I suppose I have to change something in the FeignConfiguration class, but I have searched without success.

Hope you can help me so I can get rid of Ribbon and start using Spring Cloud LoadBalancer without problems ! :C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ribbon configuration will not work for Spring Cloud LoadBalancer. If you add spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer, the default RoundRobin bean will be created for you, so you do not need to set it up. However, if you want switch to the Random algorithm, you will need to add the bean to override the default one to your configuration, like so:

```
public class CustomLoadBalancerConfiguration {

@Bean
ReactorLoadBalancer<ServiceInstance> randomLoadBalancer(Environment environment,
        LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory) {
    String name = environment.getProperty(LoadBalancerClientFactory.PROPERTY_NAME);
    return new RandomLoadBalancer(loadBalancerClientFactory
            .getLazyProvider(name, ServiceInstanceListSupplier.class),
            name); 
  }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#switching-between-the-load-balancing-algorithms).

Once you have your LoadBalancer configuration class with the new bean added, you can set your clients to use it with the `@LoadBalancerClient` or `@LoadBalancerClients` annotation. You can read in detail how to do it [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-loadbalancer-configuration).

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to create bean of type ReactorServiceInstanceLoadBalancer and it will get used in place of the default RoundRobin bean.

```
@Configuration
public class LoadBalancingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ReactorLoadBalancer<ServiceInstance> reactorServiceInstanceLoadBalancer(Environment environment,
        LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory) {
      String name = environment.getProperty(LoadBalancerClientFactory.PROPERTY_NAME);
      return new RandomLoadBalancer(
          loadBalancerClientFactory.getLazyProvider(name, ServiceInstanceListSupplier.class), name);
    }

}
```

The example above is copied from default bean creation in the LoadBalancerClientConfiguration class from the spring-cloud-loadbalancer project

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public ReactorLoadBalancer<ServiceInstance> reactorServiceInstanceLoadBalancer(Environment environment,
        LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory) {
    String name = environment.getProperty(LoadBalancerClientFactory.PROPERTY_NAME);
    return new RoundRobinLoadBalancer(
            loadBalancerClientFactory.getLazyProvider(name, ServiceInstanceListSupplier.class), name);
}
```

I'm trying to work out how all this works at the moment so that I can get the load balancing code to use a wiremock server for my tests without needing a discovery server as well. But, I've not found much useful documentation that explains how you migrate from ribbon to the spring load balancer.

The following works for me to get everything to use wiremock in my tests. Assuming I have wiremock server running locally and listening on port 9999.

```
@Bean
public RoundRobinLoadBalancer loadBalancer() {
  DefaultServiceInstance wiremock = new DefaultServiceInstance("", "", "localhost", 9999, false);
  return new RoundRobinLoadBalancer(ServiceInstanceListSuppliers.toProvider("", wiremock), "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I like your solution, at least there is no need to separately create another class and then use @LoadBalancerClient to point to it. Strange, wonder how come official document never suggest your solution approach.